# In React 17 jquery issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I'm using React. I need jquery functionality. I solved this problem with npm install jquery. But is such a use correct? I have never seen a user before. Will I encounter a problem?
[image]

Comment: React and jQuery are pretty orthogonal to one another. In React, direct DOM manipulations are very anti-pattern, and that's about all jQuery does. I don't recommend mixing the two in the least. What are you trying to use or do with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite strange to mix a framework like React with jQuery. Not completely unheard of, but it's almost never the right way to do things.

Here, you can achieve the same effect more properly by

- using `addEventListener` instead of jQuery
- using `useEffect` to add the listener *once* (and to remove it once the component unmounts)
- Setting state which changes the nav's class via JSX instead of doing it with DOM manipulation

```
const Header = () => {
  const [shrink, setShrink] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = () => {
      setShrink(window.scrollY > 50);
    }
    document.addEventListener('scroll', handler);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('scroll', handler);
  }, []);
  const navClass = (shrink ? 'shrink ' : '') + 'navbar navbar-expand-lg'; // etc
  return (
    <header>
      <nav className={navClass}>
        ...
```